# Django test: Residence() got an unexpected keyword argument 'hotel_id'

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

```
  class Hotel (models.Model):
  name = models.CharField()
  country = models.CharField()
  city = models.CharField()
  street = models.CharField() 


 class Residence(models.Model):
  hotel_id = models.ForeignKey(Hotel, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, related_name='hotel')
  house_number = models.CharField()
```

I want to join two models (Hotel and Residence) and then post it. I wrote the folowing code:

```
serializers.py

 class HotelSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
  class Meta:
    model = Hotel
    fields = ['name', 'country', 'city', 'street']


class ResidenceSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
 hotel_id = HotelSerializer()

 class Meta:
  model = Residence
  fields = ['house_number', 'hotel_id'] 
 
 def create(self, validated_data):
    return Residence.objects.create(**validated_data)
 
views.py

 class ResidenceViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
 serializer_class = ResidenceSerializer
 queryset = Residence.objects.all()
```

When I try to post data in my api I got the following error:  Residence() got an unexpected keyword argument 'hotel_id'. Can someone help me?

Comment: Please add your input data (eg. from web browser / postman)

Answer (score 0):

Replacing `hotel_id` with `hotel`. And still, you can pass hotel from view

```
class ResidenceSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
 hotel = HotelSerializer()

 class Meta:
  model = Residence
  fields = ['house_number', 'hotel'] 

Also if you are not interested in hyper links(urls) then replace 
`serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer` with `serializers.ModelSerializer`.
```

Difference between `HyperlinkedModelSerializer` and `ModelSerializer` is serializer is posted here by [Serjik](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46356868/10912122)

A simple example:

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('url', 'username', 'email', 'groups')


class GroupSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Group
        fields = ('url', 'name')
```

bash> http -a admin:yourpassword http://127.0.0.1:8000/users/

```
 "results": [
        {
            "email": "admin@min.com",
            "groups": [
                "http://127.0.0.1:8000/groups/1/",
                "http://127.0.0.1:8000/groups/2/"
            ],
            "url": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/users/1/",
            "username": "admin"
        }
    ]
```

But if you change

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
        class Meta:
            model = User
            fields = ('url', 'username', 'email', 'groups')
```

The result will be:

```
   "results": [
        {
            "email": "admin@min.com",
            "groups": [
                1,
                2
            ],
            "url": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/users/1/",
            "username": "admin"
        }
    ]
```

Comment: It does not work

Comment: @Roro can you please remove `id` from `hotel_id` inside the Residence model also?

Comment: Write simple hotel = model.ForeignKey(Hotel, so on )

Comment: when I try to run python manage.py makemigrations I got an error: ImportError: cannot import name 'contextmanage' from 'contextlib' –