# Django Rest get link to related object in OneToOne relation

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

How can I get the related object link under OneToOne relation.

I have 2 models:

```
class Model1(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=False)

class Model2(models.Model):
    mymodel1 = models.OneToOneField(Model1, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

In the Model1Serializer, how can i get the link to MyModel2 related object

ahd get a result as follows:

```
[
    {
        "title": "My obj title"
        "link2mymodel2": "http://myhost/model2/pk"
    }
]
```

where pk is the relared object

Comment: you can check HyperlinkedModelSerializer... [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46356868/10856970) answer might be helpful...

Answer (score 0):

You can add it as a property to Model1.

#### models.py

```
class Model1(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=False)

    @property
    def link2mymodel2(self):
       return self.model2.link


class Model2(models.Model):
    mymodel1 = models.OneToOneField(Model1, related_name=model2, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    link = models.URLField()
```

#### serializers.py

```
class Model1Serializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    link2mymodel2 = serializers.URLField()
    
    class Meta:
        model = Model1
        fields = ["title", "link2model2"]
```